# Can a properties class be accessed by other classes without using instantiation?

Tags: c#, winforms, properties

In a WinForms application I'm working on I'd like to have a properties class to store common variables that all the forms in the project could access in order to store and retrieve values as required.

In the past I've used a static class to store strings and int values etc, but those are fixed during coding and cannot be altered when the application is running. I'd like to use a properties class in the same manner if its possible so that I'd have read *and* write functionality.

Must I create an instance of the properties class in Form1.cs and then pass it around as a parameter in the constructor of other forms in order for them to access the fields in the properties class?

Or can this be done without instantiation?

Comment: `appconfig` sounds like a better place for the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I've understood you correctly – you don't need to do anything differently. You *can* change those while running.

You can have:

```
static class ForAll
{
    public static int i;
}
```

And use it:

```
ForAll.i = 1;
```

Comment: @ispiro & NPSF3000 - indeed I was getting confused. I just tried a little test between two forms and it works perfectly. Thank you both for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer, Yes, you have to send an instant of the class.
You can't use non static properties or methods without instant the class.

Anyway `appconfig` sounds like a better place for the data.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, gdoron. I'm a hobbyist coder, can you elaborate on the usage of appconfig? I never came across it before. Can you give me an example of its use?

Comment: @TheThing. Read [this](http://www.dotnetspider.com/tutorials/AspNet-Tutorial-AspNet-Tutorial-27.aspx) very basic tutorial

Comment: Thanks for the link, gdoron. I'll have a go at it.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the singleton pattern instead of passing the class around to each form.

```
using System;

public class Singleton
{
   private static Singleton instance;

   private Singleton() {}

   public static Singleton Instance
   {
      get 
      {
         if (instance == null)
         {
            instance = new Singleton();
         }
         return instance;
      }
   }
}
```

This ensures you have the same instance of the class and then you can share that class around with other forms. If you pass the class around to other forms it can get pretty messy.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx

Comment: Let me know if you need help understanding this more and I will be happy to help :)

Comment: Micah, it's not clear to me how I would use this to store and retrieve values across multiple classes, can you elaborate on its usage in such a scenario.